# Migrate user accounts from old LAMP website to Django

Tags: django, django-authentication

We are rebuilding our old analytics website in Django. Our old website was built with LAMP stack. We have the usernames and passwords for all our accounts in un-hashed form.

Now I want to migrate all those usernames and passwords to our Django website. All our users should be able to login to the new Django website using the same username and password. 
Can someone suggest some best practices to do this? How to achieve this objective efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

**all our accounts in un-hashed form**

Please do not do that. Django is designed for **security**. By default, Django uses the PBKDF2 algorithm with a SHA256 hash.

So, during data migration, you must pass your plain texted password through hash function and save the hash-ed password to database.

By applying the above approach, you do not need to force users to reset their password.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to export all the user accounts from the old platform into the Django `auth_users` table. With either a python script or SQL tricker-y poker-y.

Whilst this method takes a little more work from the users point of view it is the safest option (especially because you stated passwords are not encrypted).

After all usernames/ emails are in the new table I (personally) would not set a password for those migrated user accounts. Instead, make sure you have set up [django password reset screens](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetView) (this is built into django). You can then get the users to reset their own passwords allowing them access into the new application.